# Criteria API query generation

Tags: sql, hibernate, criteria

I have a pretty straight forward task to query table and filter using some parameter (this parameter is foreign key for other table).

As example Table1 contains following fields:

```
id, name , description, company_id;
```

I have a method that takes as input company_id (not company object) and returns all records from table1.
The criteria query looks as follows:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Table1.class)
       .add(Restrictions.eq("company.id", companyId));
```

The problem is that generated query is too complex because it joins a couple of tables to do this. And this query is not "production ready"

Is there any way to build criteria to have SQL query like this?:

```
SELECT * from table1 where company_id =?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use `EAGER` instead of `LAZY` fetch on some your object mapping. If you don't actually need `EAGER` use `LAZY` and it should generate more simple query with your `DetachedCriteria`.